# Raspberry Pi shuts down after starting node red

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, nodered

I have node red installed on my Pi and I have been working with it all day, no errors whatsoever. I left it on for a couple of hours and for some reason it shut down. I didn't notice and thought nothing of it. However, now when I start my Pi it works all fine, but starting node red will shut down the Pi entirely. Is there any way I can check whats going wrong? I suspect there might be an error with the flows that i have created, because the command terminal does reach the "Flows Started" stage. Also, I can find the directory where my flows are saved for the life of me so I can't delete those and try again.

Comment: Alright, I found my flows directory, deleted the one I was working on and apparently fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, periodically node-red will freeze if you include certain code within a given flow, and I occasionally find myself manually editing the flow of the recently added code to relieve the issue. I will then need to look at the console logs and try to get an idea of what is causing the issue. Node-red is fairly stable when things are running right, but I do know sometimes nodes are not programmed properly and using them can muck up the flow stability. 
This I seen happen on nodes that I import from the install palette, I would test out, such as the Arduino nodes, that I can't ever seem to get working properly and just ends up glitching and freezing my Node-red runtime. Not much I can do when I try to use these nodes via normal and these issues occur. I unfortunately end up just deleting that particular node for mean time, and hope a update comes along to fix it.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did. I doesnt really explain the Pi itself shutting down though.

Comment: Do you have any particular hardware or electronics components or peripherals attached?

Check crash logs :

     /var/log/syslog
    /var/log/dmesg    <-or kernel errors

Might give a hint. Are you running headless? A good way to tell if an app locked up vs the system is plug in a keyboard, if Cap Lock toggles, the core system is still working. 

What we do know for sure its the NR flow causes the issue. Remove nodes 1 by 1 and test stability.  Do you know what node you had to remove from the .flows file? You get all your updates? Just thinking of ways to factor out causes.

Comment: Might I note for clarity, checking if core system is not frozen via the Cap Lock toggle method, is by looking at the light indicator on the physical keyboard of the Caps Lock.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having trouble reading data slower than it should be for the application timeouts try sd cards with high data rates or free up the ram